# Python: Error in saving graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is my code for drawing a histogram and saving as `myfig.png` but an empty graph is coming while saving! My code:

```
a=df["a"].value_counts()    
plt.figure(figsize=(2,4))

sns.barplot(a.index, a.values, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('')
plt.ylabel('Number of Occurrences', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('class', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
plt.savefig("myfig.png")
```

Comment: i have edited just now it aint working

Comment: I think you have to remove the `plt.show()` command, too.

Comment: `plt.savefig("my fig.png") plt.show()` Try to fix it in order.